# Solution Verification: Prove in detail that the open rectangles in the Euclidean plane form an open base

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, solution-verification

I want some verification and/or some polishing on my proof. However if it is good, please let me know (I think this is highly unlikely to happen).

---

**Problem.** Prove in detail that the open rectangles in the Euclidean plane form an open base.

**Proof.** Let $X$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U$ and $V$ be open strips for $X$. So, we can define the open strips  $U=[(a_1,b_1)\times\mathbb{R}]$ and $V=[\mathbb{R}\times(a_2,b_2)]$. Thus we can intersect the open strips $U$ and $V$ to get an open rectangle $B$:

$$B=U\cap V=[(a_1,b_1)\times\mathbb{R}]\cap[\mathbb{R}\times(a_2,b_2)]=[(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)].$$

We let's define the collection of all open rectangles for $X$ to be

$$\mathcal{B}=\{B_i\}=U_i\cap V_j=\{\forall i,j:[(a_i,b_i)\times(a_j,b_j)]\}.$$

Thus, we can then define an arbitrary union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ to be

$$\bigcup\mathcal{B}=\bigcup\{B_i\}=\bigcup(U_i\cap V_j)=\bigcup[(a_i,b_i)\times(a_j,b_j)]=\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i)\times\bigcup_{j=1}^n(a_j,b_j)\right].$$

Therefore this defines every open set is a union of sets in this class. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The last equation is in general incorrect. The union of rectangles need not be a rectangle.

Comment: @StefanHamcke then must I just change my statement? I have fixed some of my wording.

Comment: In order to show that some collection $B$ of sets forms a base, you need to show that the intersection of any two sets in $B$ is a union of sets in $B$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke so I should define a finite intersection on $\mathcal{B}$. Then what? And the intersection is between the collection of U and V.

Comment: Just intersect $(a_1,b_1)\times(c_1,d_1)$ with $(a_2,b_2)\times(c_2,d_2)$. What do you get?

Comment: @StefanHamcke you get $[(a_1,b_1)\cap(a_2,b_2)]\times[(c_1,d_1)\cap(c_2,d_2)]$

Comment: Right. Can you express this as the product of two intervals?

Comment: @StefanHamcke no

Comment: Well, actually you can. What is $(a_1,b_1)\cap(a_2,b_2)$ ? It is $(a,b)$ with $a$ somehow depending on $a_1,a_2$, and similarly for $b$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke so if I may ask, what is the part of my proof that I have done wrong and should fix?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you are asked to show that the collection of sets of the form $(a,b)×(c,d)$ is a base (for some topology). A collection $\cal B$ is a base if for every $x\in B\cap C$ with $B,C\in\cal B$, there is a $D\in\cal B$ such that $x\in D\subseteq B\cap C$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke yes. And? What must i do? Are B, C, D collections of all b, c, d?

Comment: $B,C,D$ are products of open intervals in this problem:

Comment: @StefanHamcke what must i fix?

Comment: If you ask this way, I'd have to say: Everything. In my second-to-last comment I wrote what (I think) you are supposed to show in this problem. Also, we already nearly solved this in the previous comments.

Comment: @StefanHamcke my apologies for any offense that I may have imposed.