# Measurability from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I was following the definitions from Royden, where the measurability is given as

> We say $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is **measurable** if $\forall X \subseteq \mathbb R$
> $$m^*(X) = m^*(X \cap A) + m^*(X \setminus A)$$

Similarly,

> $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is said to be **measurable** in $\mathbb R^n$ if for all $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, $$m^\ast(X)=m^\ast(A\cap X)+m^\ast(X\backslash A).$$

> An **open rectangle** in $\mathbb R^n$ is a set of the form $R=(a_1,b_1)\times\dots\times (a_n,b_n)$. The volumn of the open rectangle is given as $\ell(R)=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2)\cdots(b_n-a_n)$.

> We then define Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R^n$ by $m^\ast: P(\mathbb R^n)\rightarrow [0,\infty)\cup\lbrace \infty\rbrace$, $$m^\ast(A)=\inf\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(R_i): A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty R_i\right\rbrace,$$

I am wondering how can we show something in $\mathbb R^n$ is measurable if each of its component is measurable in $\mathbb R$.

That is:

> Let $A=A_1\times A_2\times\cdots \times A_n\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, where each $A_i\subseteq \mathbb R$ is measurable. Prove that $A$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider sets $B_i=\mathbb{R}\times \ldots \times A_i \times \mathbb{R}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{R}$ so that if you project $B_i$ onto its $i^{th}$ component you get $A_i$ and if you project onto any other component you get $\mathbb{R}$. Then observe that $A = \bigcap_i B_i$ and that the countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand your hint correctly.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251661/solution-verification-prove-in-detail-that-the-open-rectangles-in-the-euclidean
This suggests that when taking the intersection of the open strips, it is the same as taking the intersection in their respective $\mathbb R$ space and then do the product.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to prove each $B_i$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^n$? 
I wrote For all $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, denote $X_n$ being the first component of $X$.
$$B_i \cap X = X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times (A_i \cap X_i) \times \dots \times X_n$$
$$X \setminus B_i = X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times (X_i \cap A_i^c ) \times \dots \times X_n$$
I am not sure how to combine them as there is not much property I can use.